# Is there a way to theme Atom to fit in with elementary?

Tags: software-installation, design

Is there a way to make [Atom](https://atom.io/) look more compliant with the elementary's design?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes there is. There's a special UI theme called `elementary-light-ui` that you can use. The theme was created by one of the main elementary's developers (Cassidy James). To install it, just type in the following command:

```
apm install elementary-light-ui
```

After it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+P, type `change themes`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `elementary-light-ui` as your new UI theme.

[image]

Comment: Actually worth mentioning that the theme was built by no one other than Cassidy himself ;)

Comment: @quassy I fitted that right into my answer.

Comment: There is no such package `ampd`?!

Comment: @theV0ID Someone edited my answer, there's absolutely no need to execute the `apt-get` command.